# How to derive the single harmonic oscillator propagator given the ground state wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator, path-integral, propagator

The propagator is defined to be $\langle x|U(t;0)|x'\rangle$, and assume that we know the SHO ground state wave equation

$$\psi_{0}(x)=(\frac{m\omega}{\sqrt{\pi}\hbar})^{1/2}e^{-m \omega x^2/2\hbar}$$

such that $U(t;0)|\psi_0\rangle=e^{-iE_0t/\hbar}|\psi_0\rangle$ with $E_0=\hbar \omega /2$.

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: You need to know *all* the eigenstates.  There can be  more that one system with the same ground state wavefunction.

Comment: @mikestone This is the single harmonic oscillator system so that all eigenstates are already determined. I think the problem is asking for a derivation with only the ground state being used though.

Comment: Ah... I still dont see how that is possible. Where did you find the problem?

Comment: @mikestone This is from one of my university's past exam paper. I have provided my attempt in one of the answer below.

Comment: You are aiming at Mehler s kernel  (see wikipedia) , and it look as if your have correct.

Comment: Then this is a check-my-work question and should be closed as such.

Answer (score 3):

For a single harmonic oscillator, we have

$$L=T-V=\frac 12m\dot{x}^2-\frac 12m\omega ^2x^2$$

Thus we can write done the path integral for the propagator
$$\langle x|U(t;0)|x'\rangle=\mathcal{N}\int\mathcal{Dx}(t')e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}S[x(t')]}$$

where

$$S[x(t')]=\int_0^tdt'L=\int_0^tdt'\left(\frac 12m\dot{x}^2-\frac 12m\omega ^2x^2\right)$$

The path is integrated over all possible path that start at

\begin{align*}
x(t'=0)&=x'\\
x(t'=t)&=x
\end{align*}

From the Lagrangian, we can calculate to equation of motion obeyed by a classical path $x_{cl}$

$$\ddot{x}_{cl}=-\omega^2x_{cl}$$

Now lets do a change of variable for the path integral such that

$$x=x_{cl}(t')+y(t')$$

where y satisfy boundary condition

$$y(t'=0)=y(t'=t)=0$$
\begin{align*}
S[x]&=\int_0^tdt'\frac 12 m \left({dx_{cl}\over dt'}+{dy\over dt'}\right)^2 - \frac 12m\omega ^2 (x_{cl}+y)^2\\
&=\int_0^tdt'\frac 12 m \left({dx_{cl}\over dt'}\right)^2 - \frac 12m\omega ^2 x_{cl}^2\\
&+\int_0^tdt'\frac 12 m \left({dy\over dt'}\right)^2 - \frac 12m\omega ^2 y^2\\
&+\int_0^tdt'\frac 12 m \left(2{dx_{cl}\over dt'}{dy\over dt'}\right) - \frac 12m\omega ^2 2x_{cl}y
\end{align*}

The last term vanish after integration by part and using the equation of motion:

\begin{align*}
\int_0^tdt'\frac 12 m \left(2{dx_{cl}\over dt'}{dy\over dt'}\right) - \frac 12m\omega ^2 2x_{cl}y &= \left[ 2 {dx_{cl} \over dt'}y \right]_0^t - \int_0^tdt'{1\over2}m \left( 2 {d^2x \over dt^2}y + 2\omega^2x_{cl}y \right)\\
&=0-0 = 0
\end{align*}

Thus we have
$$S[x]=S[x_{cl}]+S[y]$$

Combine our result we can write the propagator as
\begin{align*}
\langle x | U(t;0) |x' \rangle &= \mathcal{N} \int \mathcal{D}y e^{{i \over h}(S[x_{cl}+S[y])}\\
&= A(t) e^{{i \over h}S[x_{cl}]}
\end{align*}

where
$$A(t)=\mathcal{N} \int \mathcal{D}y e^{{i \over h}S[y]}$$

To calculate the exponential part of the propagator, we consider the most general solution to the classical equation of motion

$$x_{cl}(t')=\alpha \cos(\omega t')+\beta \sin(\omega t') $$

Imposing aforementioned boundary conditions, we have
\begin{align*}
\alpha &= x'\\
\beta &= {x-x'\cos(\omega t) \over \sin(\omega t)} \\
\dot{x}_{cl}(0) &= \omega \beta \\
\dot{x}_{cl}(t) &= \omega (-\alpha \cos(\omega t) + \beta \cos(\omega t))
\end{align*}

Thus
\begin{align*}
S[x_{cl}] &= \int_0^tL_{cl}\\
&=\int_0^tdt' {1\over2}m\left({dx_{cl}\over dt}\right)^2 - {1\over 2}m\omega^2x_{cl}^2\\
&= {1\over2}m\left\{[\dot{x}_{cl}x_{cl}]_{t=0}^{t=t'}-\int_0^tdt'\ddot{x}_{cl}x_{cl}-\omega ^2\int_0^tdtx_{cl}^2 \right\}\\
&={1\over 2} m \left\{\omega(-\alpha\sin(\omega t)+\beta\cos(\omega t) x - x'\omega\beta\right\}\\
&={1\over 2} m\omega  \left\{\left[-x'\sin(\omega t) + {x-x'\cos(\omega t) \over \sin(\omega t)} \cos(\omega t)\right] x - x'{x-x'\cos(\omega t) \over \sin(\omega t)} \right\}\\
&={1 \over 2} m \omega  {1 \over \sin\omega t} \left\{-x'x\sin^2\omega t + x^2 \cos \omega t - x'x\cos^2 \omega t - x'x + x'^2 \cos \omega t\right\}\\
&={m \omega  \over 2 \sin \omega t} \left\{(x'^2 + x^2 ) \cos \omega t - 2x'x\right\}
\end{align*}

By completeness relationship,
\begin{align*}
    U(t;0) |\psi_0\rangle &= \int dx' U(t;0) |x'\rangle\langle x|\psi_0\rangle\\
    e^{iE_0t/\hbar} |\psi_0 \rangle &= \int dx' U(t;0) |x'\rangle \psi_0(x')\\
    e^{iE_0t/\hbar}\langle x |\psi_0 \rangle &= \int dx' \langle x |U(t;0) |x'\rangle \psi_0(x')\\
    e^{iE_0t/\hbar} \psi_0(x) &= \int dx' A(t) e^{{i \over \hbar} S_{cl}[x,x',t]} \psi_0(x')\\
    e^{{-m\omega x^2 \over 2\hbar} - {i\omega t \over 2}} &= A(t) \int dx' e^{{i \over \hbar} \left[ {m\omega \over 2\sin\omega t} [(x^2+x'^2) \cos\omega t - 2xx']\right] - {m\omega x'^2\over 2\hbar}}
\end{align*}

Integrate the right hand side with Gaussian Integral, we have
\begin{align*}
    RHS=A(t)\sqrt{2\pi \over \left[ {m\omega \over \hbar} - {im\omega \cos\omega t \over \hbar \sin\omega t} \right]} e^{\left({im\omega x \over \hbar \sin\omega t}\right)^2 / 2 \left[ {m\omega \over \hbar} - {im\omega \cos\omega t \over \hbar \sin\omega t}\right]}e^{im\omega\cos\omega t x^2\over\hbar 2 \sin\omega t}
\end{align*}

Here we notice that $A(t)$ is an expression of t only and thus should be independent of the choice of x. Indeed, if we group together the term involving x on both left and right hand side, they will cancel each other, as you can verify.Thus we simply erase all terms containing x. That leaves us a simply expression of $A(t)$:

\begin{align*}
    A(t) &= \sqrt{{m\omega\over 2\pi\hbar}(1-{i\over\tan\omega t})}e^{-{i\omega t\over 2}}\\
    &= \sqrt{{m\omega\over 2\pi i \hbar \sin\omega t}(i\sin\omega t + \cos\omega t)}e^{-i\omega t\over 2}\\
    &= \sqrt{{m\omega\over 2\pi i \hbar \sin\omega t}e^{i\omega t}}e^{-i\omega t\over 2}\\
    &= \sqrt{{m\omega\over 2\pi i \hbar \sin\omega t}}
\end{align*}

Combining all our result, we have the final expression for SHO propagator:
\begin{align*}
    \langle x | U(t;0) |x'\rangle &= \sqrt{{m\omega\over 2\pi i\hbar \sin\omega t}}e^{im\omega\over\hbar 2\sin\omega t}{(x'^2+x^2)\cos(\omega t) - 2 x'x}\\
    &\xrightarrow{\omega \rightarrow 0} \sqrt{{m\over 2 \pi i \hbar }}e^{im(x-x')^2\over \hbar 2 t}
\end{align*}
which becomes the free particle propagator in the $\omega\rightarrow 0$ limit.